# Python, IronPython Mono

Tags: .net, macos, mono, ironpython

I have a question, Where can I find good examples or guides or can anyone give me a good example of how to get mono and ironpython working together on a MAC? I would like to do some meaningful development with it as I have had a real fascination with python and Ironpython over the last 3 months. Please any help will do.

Comment: have you been to mono-project.com and downloaded iron python  http://ironpython.codeplex.com/

Comment: You can follow @kenny's advice now, or wait for their next release, http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2010/Dec-09-1.html

Answer (score 2):

I can't provide an example (as I don't have a Mac), but it shouldn't be too difficult:

- Download the binary zip package from http://ironpython.net/download/
- unzip somewhere
- Run `mono ipy.exe`

I think IronPython works OK on Mono (and if not, please [file issues](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic)!). You might have some trouble building it, though, which the Mono team is working on.

Comment: Optionally/additionally get [PythonNet](http://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/), unzip somewhere, create the relevant symlinks described in the [ReadMe file](http://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/readme.html#installation) from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/libpython2.7.dylib to the pythonnet location.  Then mono /path/to/pythonnet/python.exe will load your native Python installation.  Yes, you can run this alongside IronPython.  :)